# Router async beforeEach triggers two routes

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to wait for an asynchronous response in my route guard. The problem is that two routes are hit.

When the page is loaded, the `/` route is triggered instantly, followed by my target route

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 500)
  })
  next()
})
```

or

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    setTimeout(next, 500)
  })
})
```

In my log I see two entries when visiting `/foo`, first `/` then `/foo` after 500ms. I'm expecting to see only the latter:

```
setup(props, { root }) {
    const hideNav = computed(() => {
      console.log(root.$route.path)
      return root.$route.meta?.hideNav
    })

    return {
      hideNav
    }
  }
})
```

I'm using `vue@2.6.12` and `vue-router@3.4.9`

Comment: can you share little example or sandbox link.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. https://jsfiddle.net/opz6wyu4/1/ , anything i miss from my reproduction code?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but this how I guard my route in a Vue component hope this helps you

```
 beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    if (store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
      Promise.all([
        store.dispatch(FETCH_ARTICLE, to.params.slug), 
        store.dispatch(FETCH_COMMENTS, to.params.slug)
      ]).then(() => {
        next();
      });
    } else {
      Promise.all([store.dispatch(FETCH_ARTICLE, to.params.slug)]).then(() => {
        next();
      });
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [beforeEnter](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard)? 
This way you can specify which routes are going to execute your function

Like this code below:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/foo',
      component: Foo,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        // ...
      }
    }
  ]
})
```